# Check Domain via Code C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have two websites.I want to validate,if the person who is signing in the 2nd website is come from the my 1st site.For example

```
if (websiteAcess == www.test.com)
{

allow user;
} 
else{

deny user;

}
```

My question is how to get the value of websiteAcess?
Please help me sort out this problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do NOT use referrer! As TomTom said it is really easy to fake (The user can modify his/her "hosts" file and can mock your 1st website and then pass the referrer check). Instead you should create some web service (not available to the user - only accessible from the websites) which associates each user with a security token while he is on the 1st website. Then when the user goes to the 2nd website just validate the token. This way you can be sure that your data is secured! Make sure that the token is long enough and cannot be guessed easily with a "Brute force" attack.

Answer (score 2):

Referrer? A variable in the request.

This is SO easy to fake, though, using it as security measure is gross neglect.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `HttpWebRequest.Referer`

Answer (score 1):

you can check it using `Request.UrlReferrer` like following

```
    if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
    {
        if (Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.Contains("www.test.com"))
        {
            //allow user;
        }
        else
        {
            //deny user;
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1) as most new programmers forgot to place that NULL check resulting crash in application

Comment: Using Request.UrlReferrer opens a huge security hole in your application! Do NOT use it!

Comment: @ Pavel Nikolov:What will be the best for this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182442/check-domain-via-code-c/4182527#4182527

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by **Request.UrlReferrer**